# How to make a job idempotent that it's multiple runs produce the same resultant file in S3

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, parquet, idempotent

I save a parquet file to S3 using spark df write.
Scenario: 
I run Job1 and save xyz.parquet to S3 where my Job2 picks up xyz.parquet and loads data to DB.
Now, I want the next time when I run Job1, it should generate xyz.parquet and load data to DB.
My problem is, I can't overwrite the parquet file, I don't want to delete old xyz.parquet file before saving new xyz.parquet coz there might be a chance where the new xyz.parquet might fail to be written and I do not want to lose my old xyz.parquet.
I want my Job1 to be idempotent so that my Job2 and other jobs do not need to be changed. 
One way of doing it is in the naming convention of the file name appended by timestamp. Is there a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

general workflow is renaming from the source dir to the dest after. S3 is special in that when you write to a file, nothing is (visibly) saved until the file close() is called. That is: if any program fails halfway through overwriting a file, the old file will still be there. Maybe you could use that feature for a workflow like

1. run query with output s3://bucket/tmp/result.parquet
2. issue s3 HTTP request `PUT s3://bucket/final/result.parquet  x-copy-source:s3://bucket/tmp/result.parquet`

None of the Hadoop FS clients to S3 expose that copy command direct, though rename does it, but forces you do delete that final one first, so there's a small vulnerability to failure there

Comment: But I can't overwrite files on S3 using hadoop clients

Comment: you can if you do a direct create(file, true) you can create a file above another one, and it wont be until you call close() That the old file gets overwritten. So it is an atomic overwrite...you just need to route the data back to your VM and up again

Comment: But I  am using a spark connector to write a file

Comment: well, not much you can do about this with the current output committers which assume that rename() is fast and reliable. S3 is not a real filesystem, and this is a key example of where the metaphor fails